# Vue 2.0 bind value prop to custom element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a custom element that requires that I pass in an object as a dom property. In Vue 2 this would typically be done like

```html
<my-element :foo.prop="{'hello': 'world'}" />
```

This works:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('my-element')[0].foo
> {hello: "world"}
```

But if I try to bind to the `value` prop:

```html
<my-element :value.prop="{'hello': 'world'}" />
```

This doesn't work. Vue stringifies the object.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('my-element')[0].value
> "[object Object]"
```

Of course I can get around this by just using a ref, but this should work, right?

https://codepen.io/rhotzq2/pen/MWbOvWo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue [treats `value` as a special key](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b51430f598b354ed60851bb62885539bd25de3d8/src/platforms/web/runtime/modules/dom-props.js#L42-L50) that is expected to be a string only (with the exception of `<progress>` elements). Therefore, the binding value is automatically stringified, and I don't see a workaround for it with normal bindings.

However, you could create a [custom binding directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) that binds `value` as an object:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  directives: {
    value: {
      inserted(el, binding) {
        el.value = binding.value
      }
    }
  },
})
```

Then use it in your template with `v-value="{...}"` (instead of `:value="{...}"`):

```html
<my-element v-value="{'hello': 'world'}">
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jOVaxEV?editors=1010)